# How do I give apache permission to use a directory on an NTFS partition?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, file-permissions, ntfs

I am running Linux (Lubutu 12.10) on an older machine with a 20GB hard drive. I have a 1 TB external hard drive with an NTFS partition on it. On that partition, there is www directory that holds my web content. It is auto-mounted at startup as /media/t515/NTFS.

I would like to change the apache document directory from /var/www to /media/t515/NTFS/www.

I need to keep the partition as an NTFS partition, because I use the same hard drive on a different machine running WAMP.

I changed the file "default" in /etc/apache2/sites-available to the new location, and restarted the server. When I tried to go to local host, I got the error:

**403 Forbidden**
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I then changed the automount options in fstab to include the option "umask=0000", and then to "umask=2200", both to no avail. I still get the same error message.

I can access the NTFS partition with no problem from other applications, and when logged in as any user. But Apache seems to be unable (or unwilling) to access the partition. How do I give apache permission to use a directory on an NTFS partition?

Comment: Actually, I got it to work without all the trouble. I had to change the permissions of the parent folders. Although /media/t515/NTFS had full permissions, /media/t515 did not have full permissions. I didn't realize that apache needs access to all directories in the path in order to work, but I found it buried in the apache documentation.

Comment: If you found a solution that's not already covered by any existing answer, please [post your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

After many many attempts here is what succeeded for me *and nothing else* that is : changing the configuration of Apache so that it uses `www-data` (Apache user) no more but my own user instead.

Very simple to do. In my version of Apache the two lines to be changed are in the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file (it can be another file in another version) :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

I replaced `www-data` by my user name (here `toto` :)) :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=toto
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=toto
```

Comment: Man, you saved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience I've always had to remount the drive with RW permissions. found this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever
```

or:

> For NTFS partitions, use the permissions option in fstab.
>
> First unmount the ntfs partition.
>
> Then edit `/etc/fstab`
>
> Graphical  `gksu gedit /etc/fstab`
>
> Command line `sudo -e /etc/fstab`
>
> Identify your partition UUID with blkid
>
> sudo blkid
>
> And add or edit a line for the ntfs partition
>
> ```
> # change the "UUID" to your partition UUID
> UUID=12102C02102CEB83 /media/windows ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
> ```
>
> Make a mount point (if needed)
>
> sudo mkdir /media/windows
>
> Now mount the partition
>
> mount /media/windows
>
> The options I gave you, auto, will automatically mount the partition
>   when you boot and users allows users to mount and umount .
>
> You can then use chown and chmod on the ntfs partition.

Both found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: method #2 is exactly what i looking for

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above solve the issue, in fact, the problem is related to Apache itself, not filesystem or permissions.

The only thing you need to do is :

```
<Directory "/www/mywebdirectoryinapartitioneddisk">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

this will solve the issue

here the post in my blog explaining everything in detail. It could work on NTFS

http://www.tbogard.com/2014/09/12/making-apache-server-to-read-a-partitioned-disk-the-definitive-solution/

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple:

1) Create a *local* user on the Windows host

2) Grant appropriate NTFS permissions to that user

3) Verify access (Windows only)

... THEN ...

4) Configure your NTFS mount on Linux to use the *same* Windows user and group (Linux user/group is irrelevant here)

5) Configure Apache to use that Linux group (Linux user/group is *essential* here)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm not entirely clear on how to do this. I have created a local user in Windows, and I have given that user full NTFS permissions. How do I edit fstab to auto-mount the partition as that windows user? And how do I configure apache after that? Do I have to create a Linux user with the same name as the Windows user I created?