# You don't have permission to access / on this server ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, configuration, mount

**Agenda:** To have an common Project Folder between Linux and Windows

I have changed my document root from : `/var/www/html` to `/media/mithun/Projects/test` in my ubuntu machine 14.04

I get error as :

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

So i added some scripts to : `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
# DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  DocumentRoot /media/mithun/Projects/test
```

But `Document Root /var/www/test` works but not with **Windows NTFS Partition Drive**.

Even after referring to :

1. [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)
2. [Issue with my Ubuntu Apache Conf file. (Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386551/issue-with-my-ubuntu-apache-conf-file-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-a)

No success :( So kindly assist me with it...

**Note:** **Projects** is an **New Volume** (Internal Drive: In Windows its E:/ Drive)

> **@Lmwangi -** Please check my updates for your reference below:
>
> **Output of :** `ls /etc/apparmor.d/`
>
> ```
> abstractions    lightdm-guest-session  usr.bin.evince         usr.sbin.cupsd
> cache           local                  usr.bin.firefox        usr.sbin.mysqld
> disable         sbin.dhclient          usr.lib.telepathy      usr.sbin.rsyslogd
> force-complain  tunables               usr.sbin.cups-browsed  usr.sbin.tcpdump
> ```
>
> **I tried killing apparmor:**
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor kill
>
> **I receive output as :** `Usage: /etc/init.d/apparmor
>   {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|recache}`
>
> **After this, i was also able to restart apache successfully**

Comment: Step 1 is to read the error_log.

Comment: Start your apache server in single processor/debug mode. Attach strace to it and find out the exact syscall that's throwing the error. Can you paste that into your question?

Comment: On another note, you can try something like sudo -u www-data "ls /media/mithun/Projects/test". My gut feeling is that you have apparmor or selinux or something similar blocking you :)

Comment: Hi @Lmwangi - I tried with `sudo -u www-data "ls /media/mithun/Projects/test"`. It threw command not found error.

Comment: Oops, just remove the quotes. Should be sudo -u www-data ls /media/mithun/Projects/test or better sudo -u www-data strace ls /media/mithun/Projects/test

Comment: Do you have apparmor or selinux installed? Try running dpkg -l | egrep "armo|seli"

Comment: @Lmwangi - I Got this output :  `ii  apparmor 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1   amd64 User-space parser utility for AppArmor
ii  dh-apparmor 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1 all AppArmor debhelper routines ii  libapparmor-perl 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1                              amd64 AppArmor library Perl bindings
ii  libapparmor1:amd64 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.1                              amd64        changehat AppArmor library
ii  libselinux1:amd64                                     2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                                    amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
`

Comment: Assuming that you don't need apparmor server wide, try to disable apparmor or uninstall it. If you need it, you can edit the Apache specific config to whitelist your /media/mithun/... path. Odds are, Apache will start serving your files after disabling/adjusting app armor (and possibly restarting Apache). Have a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=875986 or https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apparmor.html or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor. If this works, let me know

Answer (score 1):

maybe the problem is simple : is your new root directory accessible to the www-data user ? 
Try :

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data /media/mithun/Projects
```

Comment: Hi tried your code. Its throwing error as : "chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/mithun/Projects’: Operation not permitted"

Comment: try it in root. Also if you want to see if it's the real problem, try 
ls -la /media/mithun/Projects
and look at third and 4th columns if they are set to www-data (do the same for folders inside the Projects one)

Comment: I did not see it it was a windows partition ... This will be way more complicated ... Is your project going to be accessible online ? If not try to chmod 777 all your files

Comment: Sorry for not putting it earlier as windows partition. After a down vote, i analysed it to be clean and clear with all the possible efforts put into it. I tried setting permission with 777, still no dice :( Do i need to assign 777 permission for /media/mithun/Projects complete directory or /media/mithun/Projects/test (where project folder exists)

Comment: It is now quite obvious it should be a right problem because of the NTFS partition. Maybe you should try one of these solutions here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864944/how-do-i-give-apache-permission-to-use-a-directory-on-an-ntfs-partition

Comment: And also you should do chmod 777 -R /media/mirhun/Projetcs

Answer (score 1):

As you have you have discovered by now, you cannot just manipulate permissions on an NTFS partition (using tools like `chmod`)

However, you can try forcing a given owner/permissions for the entire partition when you mount it.

Now the wayto do this, depends on the NTFS-utilities you are actually using (and which i don't know, so I'm assuming you are using `ntfs-3g`)

E.g. mount the partition with the following parameters (replace `dev/sdX` with your actual partition, and `/path/to/where`drive/is/mounted` with your target path):

```
  mount -o gid=www-data /dev/sdX /path/where/the/drive/is/mounted
```

should make all the files on the partition belong to the `www-data` group.

If the filesystem sets the group ownership explicitely, this still might not work.
In this case, you might need to setup a `usermap`, that maps your windows users/groups (as found on the partition) to your linux users/groups.

The `ntfs-3g.usermap` utility will help you generate an initial usermap file, which you can then edit to your needs:

```
 ntfs-3g.usermap /dev/sdX
```

Then pass the usermap to the mount options:

```
  mount -o usermapping=/path/to/usermap.file /dev/sdX /path/where/the/drive/is/mounted
```

Comment: i tried with ur first step of  `mount -o gid=www-data /dev/sdX /path/where/the/drive/is/mounted` But failing in 2nd step - It throws error as  `Could not open "/dev/sda1"
Make sure "/dev/sda1" is not mounted`. I also unmounted using **Gparted**

Comment: I accepted the answer because of the efforts, but its not yet solved yet. Please assist with it as my bounty points was going to expire today. So thought of not wasting it in vain

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have apparmor enforcing rules that prevent Apache from reading non-whitelisted directory paths. I suggest that you

1. Edit the apparmor config for Apache to access your custom path. You'll need to hunt around /etc/apparmor.d/ .  You may also find that using apparmor in non-enforcing mode helpful.

   $ sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/*
2. Use mod_apparmor? See [this](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Mod_apparmor_example#Configure_Apache_Directories_and_Virtual_Hosts)
3. Or disable apparmor completely. See [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=875986)

My order of preference would be 1,3,2. That should fix this for you :)

Comment: Hi @Lmwangi - When i tried to follow your steps. 1st step is throwing error like [this](http://imgur.com/XHPraSH)

Comment: Do you have anything apache related on /etc/apparmor.d/* Can you post the output of ls /etc/apparmor.d/

Comment: Also, to know whether we are going down the right rabbit hole, Check whether Apache works after stopping arparmor. Stop it like this: sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor kill

Comment: So does Apache serve your directory after running 1. /etc/init.d/apparmor stop  then 2. /etc/init.d/apache restart ?

Comment: no not the custom directory.. it still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

While using ubuntu with windows I faced same issue and it is resolved by remounting drive with read and write access. Below command will help you to do that:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /disk/location /disk/new_location
```

If it is still not working then in windows os, go to the power options and disable fast startup.

When you shut down a computer with Fast Startup enabled, Windows locks down the Windows hard disk. You won’t be able to access it from other operating systems if you have your computer configured to dual-boot. Even worse, if you boot into another OS and then access or change anything on the hard disk (or partition) that the hibernating Windows installation uses, it can cause corruption. If you’re dual booting, it’s best not to use Fast Startup or Hibernation at all.

Original article: https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/